# Not too sure whats wrong

Tags: c, arrays, sum

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum_elements_with_size(int a[], int size){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i< size ; i++){
        sum= sum + a[i];
    printf("i=%d \n sum= %d \n", i, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int a[5];
    a[0]= 1;
    a[1]= 2;
    a[2]= 0;
    a[3]= 1;
    a[4]= 3;
    sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);
    printf(" sum= %d \n", sum_elements_with_size( a, 5)); 
    system( "PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm just beginning to self learn C. I'm trying to have my function return sum but when I try to `printf(" sum= %d \n", sum);`  it does not work (says "sum is unidefined"). I try adding int sum into main but then it says "uninitialized local variable used". I end up having to use `printf(" sum= %d \n", sum_elements_with_size( a, 5))` above for it to work. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: you may want to eidt the post, to make it clear your code is the solution you found (i.e that it does work)

Comment: Ah i see, but why can't i use printf("sum=....", sum) if my function returns sum?

Comment: Because the sum you are thinking of is the local variable that is returned by the function. That variable scope is only within the function and ceases to exist after it returns. You are confused because the local variable in main() is also called sum, but they are two different variables.

Comment: @Drift117 ,modifiying `sum` from a function dosen't modify `sum` in `main`. See the answers for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C variables have [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), the place in the code where they exist.  The variable `sum` inside of `sum_elements_with_size` is only in scope inside of that function.  It does not exist anywhere else.  When you add a variable named `sum` to `main` that variable is only in scope inside of `main`.  The two variables are not related to one another at all, even though they have the same name, they exist in two different scopes.

So when you tried to use the  variable `sum` variable in `main` the compiler correctly warned you that it was unintialized.  That is that it did not have a value assigned to it.  A value had been assigned to `sum` in `sum_elements_with_size`, but that is a totally different variable.

What you want to do is assign the results of `sum_elements_with_size` to a variable in `main`.  You do that as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    int sum;
    a[0]= 1;
    a[1]= 2;
    a[2]= 0;
    a[3]= 1;
    a[4]= 3;
    sum = sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);
    printf(" sum= %d \n", sum); 
    system( "PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);` runs the function, but doesn't assign the result to anything.

Perhaps you mean to write `int sum = sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the return value of your function to a variable, in your case you want to assign it to a variable named sum. So you would do:

```
sum = sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);
printf(" sum= %d \n", sum);
```

**Note that the 'sum= %d' in the printf does not assign the return value to a variable 'sum'.**

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to have my function return sum but when i try to printf(" sum= %d \n", sum); it does not work( says "sum is unidefined").

This is because `sum` variable is not defined in `main()`. The scope of variable `sum` is in only in `sum_elements_with_size`. To print the value using `sum` variable in `main()`, first you need to define the variable in `main()`.

```
int sum = 0;
sum = sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);
```

and then

```
printf(" sum= %d \n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the "sum is unidefined" because you did not declare the sum variable in the main function. Then when you do and get "uninitialized local variable used" its because you don't initialize it. You can fix both by simply putting `int sum = sum_elements_with_size( a, 5);` before your printf call.

Answer (score 0):

I test the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    printf("%f ", pow(i,2));
}
```

the output is correct:

0.000000 1.000000 4.000000 9.000000 16.000000 25.000000 36.000000 49.000000 64.000000